# Why I am getting this output in my Java code?

Tags: java, stack, queue, implementation

```
The student at the top of the stack is Gullion,Hailey

Student Mcglothlen,Shizue is removed from the stack


Here are all the elements of the Stack using an Iterator
--------------------------------------------------------
Stack$Node@3012db7c
Stack$Node@2607c28c
Stack$Node@477588d5
Stack$Node@756a7c99
Stack$Node@221a5d08
Stack$Node@70d1c9b5
Stack$Node@5d11c3f0
Stack$Node@3956f14c
Stack$Node@7afbd1fc
null


Here are all the elements in the Stack
--------------------------------------
Putney,John
Larkey,Ismael
Winkler,Isiah
Aceto,Liana
Hamill,Crissy
Caraway,Elmira
Gullion,Hailey
Rodrigez,Jonie
Madruga,Terrell
Williams,Diego
```

The first list of elements of the Stack using an Iterator apparently is not working.  I do not know why. Here is my code for Iterator in my Stack class:

```
public Iterator<Student> iterator()  { return new ListIterator();  }

// an iterator, doesn't implement remove() since it's optional
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Student> {
    private Node<Student> current = top;

    public boolean hasNext()  { 
        return current != null;                     
    }

    public void remove() { 
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();  


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Student next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        current = current.next; 
       return (Student)current;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my Driver class that is where there seems to be a problem:

```
System.out.println("\nHere are all the elements of the Stack using an Iterator");
  System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
  Iterator <Student> iter = myStack.iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext() )
      System.out.println(iter.next() );
```

HERE IS ALL OF THE CLASSES:

Stack: http://pastebin.com/2HVLVHuM

Queue class: http://pastebin.com/3q537kHW

Student class: http://pastebin.com/UnBB7kPA

Driver class: http://pastebin.com/yeA34MNd

I CAN ONLY WRITE CODE IN THE STACK CLASS. The point of this was to Implement a stack using queues. Hope this helps

Comment: Shouldn't hasNext() method should check that current.next != null instead of current != null?

Comment: Also, how can "current" be both a Student and a Node? It seem that next returns a Node. What does Node#toString look like?

Comment: `Stack$Node@3012db7c` That's something returned by the toString of Node inside Stack.

Comment: private Student current = top; instead of: private Node<Student> current = top;

Comment: You need to show your Node class so that someone can advise you on how to get the student out of the Node and return that instead of the Node.

Comment: If were doing it right then you should have to use that `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` there. You will have to post the whole code, I think.

Comment: @breezee it is even worse,the top element is never returned by next. HasNext makes sense after that is fixed.

Comment: i will show you my entire code in pastebin links. one second

Comment: I'm curious: how the heck aren't you getting a `ClassCastException` for casting a `Node<Student>` to a `Student`??

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `toString()` method in your `Student` class. The Iterator is working correctly, but the `System.out.println()` doesn't know how to display the `Student`.

Add something to the `Student` class like this...

```
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
```

So that when you call `System.out.println()`, it can output a real value. When you call `System.out.println(Object)`, it always tries to output the `toString()` value. If this method isn't defined, it will output the java ID of the object, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: I have a seperate Student class that is not shown here that has a toString method that does that.

Comment: Have you tried `System.out.println(iter.next().toString());` - does this give the correct output? Also, your `while` loop should actually be `while (iter.hasNext() != null)` so that it doesn't write `null` on the last line

Answer (score 2):

First of all, see nneonneo 's answer for the incorrect cast in your `next()` method.

*Secondly, your Iterator implementation is incorrect.*

The `next()` function in your iterator returns the element `current` after setting it to `current.next` .

After calling `next()` on the last element of your iteration, `hasNext()` should return false. But it doesn't, because `current` still points to the element you just returned. So you will call `next()` again. And in this method, `current = current.next` will set `current` to `null`, and then return it. Which should not happen, since hasNext was true, right?

For the same reason, the fist elemtent of your stack is missing: You set `current` to the top element of your stack, but before outputting anything, you already switch to `current = current.next`. You should do that *after* doing the output.

Comment: I don't understand how to fix my code from what you're saying. sorry

Answer (score 2):

`current` in your `Stack` iterator is defined as `Node<Student>`. You return `current` from your `next()` method using a cast.

So, `next()` returns a `Node<Student>` (type-cast to `Student`), instead of an actual `Student`. Since `Node` presumably doesn't have a `toString` method, you get the default output (`Stack$Node@<addr>`).

To fix, return something like `current.item` from `next()` instead (assuming that the item stored in the `Node` is called `item`).

Comment: Based on the source of `Node` from above, it's probably `node.data`, except that's private, so he'll probably need a getter method or something.

Comment: this is due at midnight and i just need some answers now. i am stuck and running out of time, please help

Answer (score 1):

> The first list of elements of the Stack using an Iterator apparently is not working. I do not know why.

Because your iterator is returning a `Node<Student>` instead of a student. The problem is at:

```
return (Student)current;
```

You probably tried to do this, but got an Incompatible Type error:

```
return current;
```

So you tried to fix by casting.  The problem is that a node is not a student. A node contains a student.  You need to return the student that the node contains.

Try this:

```
    return current.data;
```

No casting is required because the compiler knows that the "data" member of node is a Student, since you declared current of type `Node<Student>`.  This will fix the problem where your student prints out incorrectly.  However as pointed out by @Konstantin, your iterator is still broken.  You need to save the value of current in a temporary variable, move current, then return the temporary variable.  Here is one possible implementation:

```
    public Student next() {
        if (current == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Node<Student> result = current;
        current = current.next;
        return result.data;
    }
```

[epilogue]

You really need to review the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  It's not clear from the code you pasted in above but it's obvious in the paste-bin code that you are using Student as a type parameter.  That is very non-standard and confusing.  The convention is to use a capital letter - typically T.  You should have declared stack like below.  Everywhere you use Student, replace it with T.

```
public class Stack <T> implements Iterable<T>{   // good
```

instead of

```
public class Stack <Student> implements Iterable<Student>{ // bad
```

T means some type to be decided later and you can use Stack with any kind of object.  Only when you actually create a stack to you use Student (or whatever)

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Stack<Student> x = new Stack<Student>();
```

Comment: Wait! Everything works except it isn't adding the last person at the end of the stack using the iterator

Comment: hasNext is broken. The one in paste bin. It's checking current.next instead of current. The version above is correct.  Go back to the version you pasted in above.